# Login error while hosting Website using IIS

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

My website is designed in Visual Studio (Asp.net and c# on my local machine).

If I run website from Visual Studio, its running fine, but when I publish this website (hosting on IIS) I am getting this error:

> Server Error in '/HeadCount' Application.
>
> Login failed for user 'AUTH\VENUGOPALS13$'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed
>   for user 'AUTH\VENUGOPALS13$'.

How can I solve this problem?

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHJwc.png)

Comment: Hi! Please, specify, what environment do you use. In the question I see IIS, in tags c#, visual studio, asp.net. What have you tried to do, and where do you stuck?

Comment: Using Visual studio(Asp.net and c#) this website is designed. If i running website from visual studio, its running fine. Now I have published this website and i am hosting in on IIS, from here i am browsing it and getting this error

Comment: Are you using shared hosting or your own server?

Answer (score 0):

The credentials in the connection string are wrong, or the server does not allow Windows User logins, or it does not allow this *specific* user.

Check if SQL Server is configured for Windows Authentication Mode or Mixed Authentication Mode. Then check if the user is allowed (e.g. try to connect from SQl Management Studio with this user).

If you can login then the connection string is somehow wrong. Here is a good way to construct a working connection string:

- Create an empty text file, e.g. using Explorer -> right click -> **New Text Document**, name it "**temp.udl**".
- Double click "**temp.udl**", so a "Data Link Properties" wizard appears. Set all the fields & boxes as desired (starting from the first Tab), press [**Test Connection**], and once it succeeds, press [OK].
- Copy the connection string that is now present in the UDL file to your application.

Comment: I am able to login to the SQL server with Windows Authentication Mode but I have taken remote connection for SQL. and visual studio is in my local system

Comment: Edited my answer, see it please.